# How to link a library to a program in turbo C++?

Tags: dll, turbo-c++

I have created a dynamic library file (dll) on Windows, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I want to use the library now from a program in Turbo C++. How do I link the program and library from Turbo C++?

Comment: dll is used at run time; At compiled time the .lib is used. Just add the generated <dll_name>.lib file to the list of files being compiled.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Can you explain that in detail, please? Sorry!